# How do I pass an array from a rake task to a mailer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a task that iterates through some records and adds updated records to an array. I want to send a single email to a recipient, and in the view, use that array in a loop.

```
task :build_array => :environment do
  records = []
  Record.all.each do |record|
    if record.attribute == 'condition'
    records << record
  end
  RecordMailer.matching_records(records).deliver unless records.blank?
end
```

...

```
class RecordMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def matching_records(records)
    mail(to: 'user@email.com', subject: 'Matching Records')
    @records = records
  end
end
```

...

```
%p Lookie here, you have matching records!
%ul
  - @records.each do |record|
    %li= record.title
```

When I run my rake task, I get an `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` error. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how mailers work or something?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo there. Method name is `matching_records` but you called `matching_record`.

Update:

```
@records = records
mail(to: 'user@email.com', subject: 'Matching Records')
```

Comment: Sorry, the typo is only in my illustration here.

Comment: Then just change the order to something like my updates

Comment: Changing the order didn't make a difference.